# Password Strength validator not submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, web, jquery-plugins, coldfusion

I am using a plugin called pStrength.jquery.js and it was working previously but for some reason it has stopped, i am not sure if i am doing anything wrong.

This is the code on my page

```
    <cfinclude template="header.cfm">
    <cfparam name="ERROR" default="">
    <cfparam name="FORM.ACTION" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.NEWPASS1" default="">
    <Cfparam name="form.NEWPASS2" default="">
    <cfparam name="message" default="">

    <style>
        #myElement1, #myElement2 {
        padding:4px;
        margin:2px;
        border:solid 1px #999;
        }

        #myElement2 {
        background-color:#036;
         }

    div {
        margin-left:20px;
        margin-top:6px;
    }
    .left {
        float:left;
    }
    .clear {
        clear:both;
    }
     </style>


    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="780" class="Border" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td class="Navsub" align="left" colspan="2">Reset Password</td>
    </tr>


    <cfif FORM.ACTION eq "CHANGE">
    <Cfif form.NEWPASS1 neq form.NEWPASS2>
    <Cfset error = 1>
    <Cfset message = "Your passwords did not match. Please retry">
    <Cfelse>
        <cfquery name="update_password" datasource="#application.db#">
            update tbladmin set adminpass = '#form.newpass1#' where adminid = #session.adminid#
    </cfquery>
    <Cfset error = 0>
    <cfset message = "Your password has been updated. You will be required to enter it the next time you login">
</Cfif>
```

```
    <cfoutput>
    <form id="myForm" action="?#createuuid()#" method="post">
    <Cfif error neq "">
     <Tr>
     <Td align="center" class="Error" colspan="2" bgcolor="##fb565d">#message#</Td>
     </Tr>
    </Cfif>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" class="Copy" valign="middle">New Password:</td>
    <td align="left" class="Copy" valign="top"><input name="NEWPASS1" type="password" class="textblock" required="yes" message="Please enter your new password" id="myElement1" data-display="myDisplayElement1"><div class="left" id="myDisplayElement1"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" class="Copy" valign="middle">Confirm Password:</td>
    <td align="left" class="Copy" valign="top"><input name="NEWPASS2" type="password" class="textblock" required="yes" message="Please re-enter your new password" id="myElement2" data-display="myDisplayElement2"><div class="left" id="myDisplayElement2">       </div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">
    <input type="submit" name="Action" value="Change" class="submitbutton"></td>
    </tr>

    </form>
    </cfoutput>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/pStrength.jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#myForm').submit(function(){
            return false;
        });

        $('#myElement1, #myElement2').pStrength({
            'changeBackground'          : false,
            'onPasswordStrengthChanged' : function(passwordStrength, strengthPercentage) {
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $.fn.pStrength('changeBackground', this, passwordStrength);
                } else {
                    $.fn.pStrength('resetStyle', this);
                }
                $('#' + $(this).data('display')).html('Your password strength is ' + strengthPercentage + '%');
            },
            'onValidatePassword': function(strengthPercentage) {
                $('#' + $(this).data('display')).html(
                    $('#' + $(this).data('display')).html() + ' Great, now you can continue to change your password!'
                );

                $('#myForm').submit(function(){
                    return true;
                });
            }
        });
    });
     </script>
     <cfinclude template="footer.cfm">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you open up the debug tools on your browser, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi! I am using Firebug (Firefox Plugin) and there are no errors, just two warnings. 1-"
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen." 2-"Password fields present in a form with an insecure (http://) form action. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen."

Comment: When i submit the form Firefox gives me a pop-up asking me which account i would like to change the password for, i then select the account i am logged in as but then nothing happens

Comment: Why is this tagged as ColdFsuion? It is not a ColdFusion issue.

Comment: Well i am using coldfusion and was not sure where the issue was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not removing the other submit event, you are just appending to it.

This is not overrding the return false version you defined before.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    return true;
});
```

You either need to remove it

```
$('#myForm').off("submit").submit(function(){
    return true;
});
```

or better yet, do not assign a new function, use booleans.

```
var isValid = false;
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    return isValid;
});
```

and inside the validation checks, set it to true or false.

Comment: Hi Epascarello, i have a problem now that the form is being submitted even if my values are invalid. i removed the code as you said and replaced it with "$('#myForm').off("submit").submit(function(){
    return true;
});"

Comment: could you maybe show me how you would do the second option? I am not very good with javascript at all as my colleague usually takes care of that, hes sick today so im stuck with it